# Is it possible to run the transformer (performer) SLiM without using GPUs?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

This question is about the article [Sub-Linear Memory How to Make Performers SLiM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.11346.pdf).

I googled for the fastest transformer and I think almost surely I found. It is called SLiM.

The problem is the authors use only GPUs and I don't understand much about GPUs.
I don't even know whether there are algorithms that run only on GPUs and are impossible to run on usual hardware.

SLiM is implemented with Tensorflow and uses prefix-sum algorithm.

Does SLiM has something I am missing or I am not aware that makes its implementation disadvantageous (compared to Performers) on CPUs?

Will SLiM run very slowly on common hardware?
How many times is SLiM slow when it runs on common hardware?

Note: I am interest in using for other tasks than described in the above cited paper like question answering in a collection of the order of millions of documents so I don't have memory to test the big $O$ constants in the algorithms... (and I can't afford to buy GPUs...)

Comment: Any algorithm that can be run on GPUs can also be run on CPUs. GPUs are just faster for specific tasks, while CPUs where designed to be general and do all sorts of things.

Comment: Is there a less expensive hardware than GPUs and make the same work as GPUs @nir shahar? (The backward and forward pass of the optimization process is compatible with GPUs and can be done in parallel but I don't understand the GPU architeture...)

Comment: I honestly don't know. I also don't really understand the GPU architecture

Comment: I would like to know the more adequate and cheaper hardware than GPU. Should I delete this question and ask another question or edit this question?